# How can I access Start Menu search functionality over RemoteApp?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, start-menu, remoteapp

I use [RemoteApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#RemoteApp) on a daily basis for accessing remote applications using my local desktop window manager. This has worked very well for me, particularly while working from home during the current pandemic, and I am very happy with my current workflow using RemoteApp.

However, a constant complaint of mine is that I lack access to the host system Start Menu search functionality. I really enjoy the indexed Start Menu searches, including contents like my Start Menu shortcuts, system settings, recent files, etc.

How can I access the Start Menu indexed search functionality without having access to the host system desktop window manager?

A few things I've tried so far with no success:

- A script to raise the Start Menu dialog: I haven't been able to find a way to trigger this without using the Windows key, and triggering a remote keypress (e.g., via AutoHotkey) doesn't appear to work without access to the DWM.
- Using the [`search-ms` protocol](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-qryidx-searchms): I'm able to access this through Windows Explorer, but this appears to just use the standard file system search functionality rather than the indexed Start Menu search.
- A separate utility which runs searches itself: I haven't been able to find any such tool.

For additional context, both the host and client machine are running Windows 10 Enterprise version 20H2.

** Disclaimer: I'm not sure that saying I don't have "access to the DWM" is technically correct. RemoteApp seems analogous to X11 forwarding to me. What I really mean is that I have access to the rendered window, but lack access to the desktop as a whole.*